# MonoDroid OnConfigurationChanged Not Firing

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I've seen a number of other questions on the subject, but so far none of the answers have fixed my issue.  I basically just don't want my activity to get recreated every time the screen is reoriented.  From what I've found, the below should work:

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="internalOnly" android:versionCode="1">
  <application android:label="Service Portal">
    <activity android:name =".CallManagement" android:configChanges="orientation"></activity>
  </application>  
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

CallManagement.cs

```
public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Android.Content.Res.Configuration newConfig)
    {
        base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

I've tried changing android:configChanges to "orientation|keyboardHidden".  As I'm targeting API level 10, the suggestion I've seen a number of times to also include "screenSize" does not apply.

I put a breakpoint in the OnConfigurationChanged void and it never catches and OnCreate is definitely continuing to run. What am I doing wrong or am I misunderstanding what this functionality is supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried screen locking in a particular orientation?

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape">.
```

I lock the screen programatically, I haven't found the layout as good as requesting the orientation and then locking the orientation with the provided int.

If you don't want to lock the screen, but want the activity to resize correctly on orientation change, you might re-consider your design.  Saving game state and then allowing android to re-create the activity is considered the best practice for a dynamic screen.

Comment: I definitely do not want to lock the screen orientation.  Users need to be able to interact with the app in whichever orientation is most comfortable.  The biggest issues I'm having with the change is with Dialogs and a dynamic Spinner. In OnCreate the spinner is given an ArrayAdapter whose options change based on other factors. If I select the item in position 1 and reorient, in OnCreate it bebuilds the list of options based on the new situation during OnCreate and now what is in position 1 is not what was there.

Comment: So - could you save the selection based on some unique option id (name or hash) and then select whichever object matches your saved value, in the on-create?  I very much agree with you that there is little control over the app on screen change, but again, its meant to be a 'feature' not a bug.

Comment: Not really. The item selected in landscape may not even be an option in the spinner when turned portrait and the ArrayAdapter rebuilds in onCreate. The options in the spinner are meant to control workflow, so based on where the user currently is, the options change.  I have the user's selection as soon as the item is selected in the spinner.    I guess I could just always force the spinner to select a generic "Select" item on reorientation.  But that doesn't help with the dialog issue?